# Conditional route change animations based on target/source route

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular2-routing

I went through the whole [animation documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) provided by the Angular 2 team so I've got an understanding of how it works.

I was able to apply animation to my components when the route changes (`:leave` and `:enter` states).

What I'd like to do now is to apply route change animations only if `page1` goes to `page2` and don't apply if transitioning from `page1` to `page3`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page1',
  templateUrl: './page1.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('routerTransition', [
    state('void', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' })),
    state('*', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' })),

    transition(':leave', [
      style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
    ])
  ])
  ],
  host: { '[@routerTransition]': '' }
})
export class Page1 {}
```

Is there a way I can pass the `Router` provider to the `animations` property and only apply the animation if target route is `page2`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to inject Router to the animation property so I rolled out my own.

CSS

```
#page1 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;

    &.leave {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="page1" [ngClass]="{ 'leave': isLeaving }"><a (click)="go()">Go</a></div>
```

JS

```
go() {

  this.isLeaving = true;

  // awaits for animation to finish
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/page2']);
  }, 400);

}
```